# React Flow - one nodes drags other nodes

Tags: react-flow

After upgrading to version 10, I see that sometimes when I move one node, it drags several other nodes with it.
[image]
My Code ( nothing special):

```
 const onNodesChange = useCallback(
    (changes) => {
        if (nodesToShowRef.current && edgesToShowRef.current) {
            setElementsToShow(applyNodeChanges(changes, nodesToShowRef.current), edgesToShowRef.current)
        }
    },
    [setElementsToShow]
);

<ReactFlow ref={ref => mapRef.current = ref}
            onClick={(e) => {
                ....
            }}
            minZoom={0.1}
            edgeTypes={edgeTypes}
            nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
            connectionLineComponent={FloatingConnectionLine}
            nodesDraggable={true}
            nodesConnectable={true}
            nodes={nodesToShow}
            edges={edgesToShow}
            fitView
            attributionPosition={"top-left"}
            noWheelClassName="no-wheel"
            selectNodesOnDrag={false}
            elementsSelectable={false}
            onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
            onNodeClick={(ev, node) => {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ...
            }}
            onEdgeClick={(ev, edge) => {
                ev.stopPropagation();
               ...
            }}
            onEdgeUpdate={onEdgeUpdate}
            onConnect={onConnect}
            onNodeContextMenu={(event, node) => {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
               ...
            }}
            onEdgeContextMenu={(event, edge) => {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                ...
            }}
            onContextMenu={onMapContextMenu}
            onNodeDragStop={onNodeDragStop}
        >
```

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: It must be very late, but I've just found your question. I bet your problem was that those nodes accidentally had same ID?

Comment: Don't think so. I'm not working on this project anymore.